# Unable to assign value using javascript

Tags: javascript, safari

I've tried various things found here on SO, but I cannot get this to work. Below is my entire HTML test document. I'm loading it with the following url:

`file:///Users/aaronbratcher/Documents/Tester.html?Donor.firstName=John&Donor.lastNameBusiness=Smith`

What I'm expecting is for the 2 text fields to be populated by the javascript with the values passed on the URL, however they are not being populated. The log messages indicate everything is found as expected. No errors or warnings reported.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Accept Donation</title>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="AcceptDonation" action="http://localhost" onsubmit="return review()" method="get">
        <H2>Donor Name</H2>
        <div class="table-field">
            <input type="text" class = "textField fullWidth" name = "Donor.firstName" id="firstName" autocorrect="off" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="table-field bottom">
            <input type="text" class="textField fullWidth" name = "Donor.lastNameBusiness" id="lastName" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        </form>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        var urlParameters = {}
        var kMinReceiptRequiredAmount = 250

         window.onload = function () {
            loadParameters()
        }

        function loadParameters() {
            var url = window.location.search.substring(1)
            var parts = url.split("&")
            for (var i=0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                var parameter = parts[i]
                var parameterParts = parameter.split("=")
                var parameterKey = decodeURI(parameterParts[0])
                var parameterValue = decodeURI(parameterParts[1])

                var docObject = document.getElementsByName(parameterKey)
                console.log(docObject)
                console.log(parameterValue)
                if (docObject) {
                    docObject.value = parameterValue
                }
            }           
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're even logging `docObject`, the issue can clearly be seen in the console.

Comment: only obvious if you realize that the brackets indicate an array of objects :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.getElementsByName()` function returns a **list** of elements, even if there's only one on the page that matches.

```
  if (docObject && docObject.length)
    docObject[0].value = parameterValue;
```

You don't *really* need to test whether the return value is non-empty because `.getElementsByName()` always returns a NodeList.

```
  if (docObject.length)
    docObject[0].value = parameterValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementsByName` which returns a `nodeList`. So when you're setting the value of the text field element you need to access it from the list similar to the way you would if it were in an array.

```
var docObject = document.getElementsByName(parameterKey)
console.log(docObject)
console.log(parameterValue)
if (docObject.length) {
    docObject[0].value = parameterValue
}
```

If possible I would change it so you're looking up the element by `id` rather than `name`. Using `getElementsByName` is useful if there are multiple fields with that name. Using `getElementById` is useful if there is only one field with that id, and then you won't need to worry about working with a `nodeList`